# How to integrate Google Docs/Excel with Jenkins to automatically populate Pass/Fail field

Tags: excel, jenkins, automation, google-docs

Im relatively new to this industry, and Ive just received my first assignment. Im not looking to take up too much of anyone's time, Im just looking for a little guidance.

I need to create a spreadsheet with "Ticket ID", "Test Case ID", "Pass/Fail" and "Comments" columns.

We have builds running on/managed by Jenkins, and we have failed builds more often than not.

Id like to link/integrate this spreadsheet with Jenkins, so that way the document is automatically populated with data.

(Please see attached image for a better visual of what Im trying to realize)

If a build passes, populate "Pass/Fail" column in spreadsheet with "Pass" and "Comments" column with "Build passed"

If a build fails, say "Failed" and import the "Comments" from Jenkins why the build the failed

Any advice would be much appreciated, thank you. Also, if you have a suggestion of a better way to do this, please let me know.

[image: Spreadsheet]

Answer (score 0):

Probably your best choice would be using a Groovy post-script to fill in your Excel table. Using Groovy you can access Jenkins' environment variables and get the status of each job. In order to use Groovy you'll need this plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin